Issue with Table Border in Outlook Emails: White Line Appears Above Bottom Borders at Zoom Levels Above 100%
I am using an Excel macro to compose an Outlook email that is based on an external HTML file. The email looks perfect when zoomed to 100%. However, when zooming in (e.g., to 120%), a white line appears above the bottom borders in all the tables.
Problem:

When zooming the email in Outlook to more than 100%, a white line appears above the bottom border of the tables.
The issue doesn't occur at 100% zoom, and everything looks normal.
This behavior disrupts the email's appearance at different zoom levels.

What I've Tried:

I’ve reviewed the table and border-related CSS properties in the HTML, but the issue persists across zoom levels.
I suspect the issue could be related to how Outlook handles rendering at higher zoom levels, but I’m not sure how to fix it.

What I Need:

Fix the CSS: Adjust the CSS in my HTML file to prevent the white line from appearing, regardless of the zoom level in Outlook.
Maintain design consistency: Ensure the email design remains consistent, responsive, and looks as intended across different zoom levels in Outlook.

Here’s a snippet of the current HTML/CSS that defines the table and border properties:
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        html {
            font-size: 11px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%
        }

        body {
            font-size: 11px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%
        }

        table.data {
            cell-spacing: 0px;
            cell-padding: 0px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: none;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            background-color: white
        }


        td.tdcontent {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans serif;
            font-size: 11px;
            border-bottom: solid 1px #dddddd;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-right: 10px;
            text-align: justify;
        }

        td.tdcomment {
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans serif;
            font-size: 11px;
            color: #004499;
            border-bottom: solid 1px #dddddd;
            border-left: solid 1px #dddddd;
            text-align: right
        }

        td.tdheader {
            border: solid 1px #00915A;
            background-color: #00915A;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans serif;
            font-weight: bold;
            ;
            padding: 3px 2px 2px 7px;
            font-size: 11px
        }

        td.tdsuperheader {
            border: solid 1px #00915A;
            background-color: #00685E;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans serif;
            font-weight: bold;
            ;
            padding: 3px 2px 2px 7px;
            font-size: 11px
        }




    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <center style='width:100%'>
        <h1>test table</h1>
        <table class='data' width=670 cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
            <tr>
                <td class='tdsuperheader' width='60%'>
                    <div><span
                            style='color:#FFFFFF;font-size:11px;font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;'>test heading</span></div>
                </td>
                <td class='tdsuperheader' width='40%' style='text-align:right;color:#ffffff'>
                    &nbsp;test&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class='tdheader' width='60%'>
                    <div><span
                            style='color:#FFFFFF;font-size:11px;font-style:normal;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none;'>test sub heading</span></div>
                </td>
                <td class='tdheader' width='40%' style='text-align:right;color:#aaccaa'>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class='tdcontent' width='60%'>
                    <div><span
                            style='color:#000000;font-size:11px;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:none;'>test content</span></div>
                </td>
                <td class='tdcomment' width='40%'>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            
        </table>

    </center>
</body>
<html>

And here is the VBA code that generates the email draft.
Sub CreateEmail()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim htmlFilePath As String
    Dim fileNum As Integer
    Dim fileContent As String
    Dim lineContent As String

    ' Set the file path to the HTML file
    htmlFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\file.html"

    ' Initialize file content variable
    fileContent = ""

    ' Get a free file number
    fileNum = FreeFile

    ' Open the HTML file for input
    Open htmlFilePath For Input As #fileNum

    ' Read the HTML file line by line and append to the fileContent string
    Do While Not EOF(fileNum)
        Line Input #fileNum, lineContent
        fileContent = fileContent & lineContent & vbCrLf
    Loop

    ' Close the file
    Close #fileNum

    ' Create Outlook application and mail item
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    ' Set the email properties
    With OutMail
        .HTMLBody = fileContent
        .Subject = "Your Subject Here"
        .To = "recipient@example.com"
        .Display ' Display the email draft
    End With

    ' Cleanup
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub



Expected Outcome:
The table should display correctly in Outlook at any zoom level without the appearance of white lines above the bottom borders.
Any suggestions or CSS fixes that could resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Screenshots of the issue
Normal table.

Zoomed-in table.

Zoomed-in table.

